# Тип объекта или его наследника

Tags: классы, java

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

vs.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

Благодаря позднему связыванию,переопределяемые методы вызываться будут из наследуемого класса.В чем разница таких объявлений?
PS вопрос касается не только контейнеров, но и любых наследуемых классов.

Comment: Хорошо бы параметр типа указывать в объявлении переменной.

Comment: дадаокейокей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть в сокрытии подробностей реализации и уменьшении кол-ва зависимостей в виде конкретных классов.

`List` определяет, что можно сделать с объектом данного типа (если порядок неважен, можно использовать более общий тип: `Collection` или даже `Iterable`), `ArrayList` - в данном случае указывает на то, как именно реализован список.

Чаще всего подробности неважны для клиентского кода и принято их скрывать.

Comment: а как в данном случае уменьшится кол-во зависимостей? И так уж критично скрывать от клиента подробности реализации списка ?Хотелось бы примера, когда критично

Comment: @voipp В данном конкретном случае кол-во зависимостей не уменьшится. Что касается примера, то его несложно придумать. Представьте, что вы знаете конкретную имплементацию `List`, возвращаемую неким библиотечным методом. В своем коде вы приводите `List` к известной вам имплементации и используете ее специфические возможности. А потом автор библиотеки берет, и меняет конкретную имплементацию на другую. Ваш код ломается.

Answer (score 2):

Разница вот в чем - создавая объект типа интерфейса или типа родительского класса, этот объект будет иметь доступ только к методам, объявленным в интерфейсе или родительском классе, попытка вызвать метод, который есть в дочернем классе, но которого нет в родительском или интерфейсе вызовет исключение.

Comment: > вызовет исключение

Ошибку компиляции, а не исключение.